# Is this "INFO: Maximum number of threads (xxx) created" still remain inTomcat 9"

Tags: tomcat9

I've tried to stimulate Tomcat 9 thread pool load test, and want to get the log from catalina.out to show

> INFO: Maximum number of threads (750) created for connector with address null and port 8081

When the thread reach 750 which was setup in Tomcat 9.

In Tomcat 6, I could see this log but in Tomcat 9, I couldn't find this log when reach the thread maximum.

the solution or what is difference between Tomcat 6 and 9